# Get Images From File In a Directory As Integers

Tags: java, android

I am storing some images in `List` Initialized by `Integer`. I want to add images from the user directory in the same manner but I have trouble converting the files to `int`.

Some methods only accept integers from resource values and hence one needs to change an image to the form of the resource.

```
sampleMethod(R.drawable.pic1);
sampleMethod(filePath); //change this to a resource integer
```

Help me out

Comment: Don't create a multiple questions:- https://stackoverflow.com/q/50076214/3974530

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Image Link URL To Integer Drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076214/convert-image-link-url-to-integer-drawable)

Comment: @InsaneCat this refers to the file sytem no the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are not identified by integers. You cannot use `List<Integer>` to hold references to files.

Resources are identified by integers, largely because they are not files on the device's filesystem. They are only files on your development machine.

It is unclear where and how you are using the code from your code snippet. You might consider defining an `ImageSource` interface, with `ResourceImageSource` and `FileImageSource` implementations, then hold a `List<ImageSource>`.

Comment: Thanks, some methods in android only accept the resource int and thats the reason for this. Can you advice on implementing "https://github.com/moritz-wundke/android-page-curl" in another way?

Comment: @Lucem: "some methods in android only accept the resource int and thats the reason for this" -- then either you cannot use files or you need to find other solutions for whatever it is that you are trying to do. "Can you advice on implementing..." -- that GitHub repo has fairly old code, and it is not a library. I don't know what you mean by "implementing" that repo. You might see if there is [a library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/24) that does what you seek.